# C++ smart pointers confusion

Tags: c++, c++11, sqlite, smart-pointers

I understand that in the C++ realm it is advocated to use smart pointers. I have a simple program as below.

```
/* main.cpp */
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

/* SQLite */
#include "sqlite3.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // unique_ptr<sqlite3> db = nullptr; // Got error with this
    shared_ptr<sqlite3> db = nullptr;

    cout << "Database" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile with unique_ptr line got an error message:

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'sqlite3'
 error C2338: can't delete an incomplete type
```

When I compile with shared_ptr line it is successful. From several questions and answers my understanding is that unique_ptr should be preferred as I do not intended to have objects sharing resources. What is the best solution in this case? Use shared_ptr or go back to the old approach of bare pointers (new/delete)?

Comment: You'll find that new/delete approach is not an option either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`sqlite3`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/sqlite3.html) is an *opaque structure* (much like `FILE` from C). All you have is its declaration, not its definition. That means you can't use it in a `std::unique_ptr` directly without a custom deleter.

Comment: Yes, from several other questions and answers I got that too. What is the alternative then?

Comment: @Amani Create a custom deleter (if you can't use [`sqlite3_close`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/close.html) directly)?

Comment: is there any cost of using shared_ptr even when no resource sharing is intended?

Comment: @Amani Yes, the shared state will still be allocated, even if there's only one instance.

Comment: @Amani compared to cost of initializing SQLite the overhead of managing a shared_ptr is in the noise.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's worth pointing out that the reason a customer deleter is not required for `std::shared_ptr<T>` is simply that `db` is constructed using a special constructor overload.   With `unique_ptr<T>` you have to specify a custom deleter with a template argument, but for `shared_ptr<T>` can do so per-object with the constructor.  Try constructing using the other overloads, and it won't compile either when the compiler discovered that `sqlite3` objects lack a destructor declaration too.

Answer (score 7):

The general approach is in @SomeProgrammerDudes's answer (accept it). But to address your concerns I'm posting this.

You shouldn't go back to raw new and delete. Neither because `sqlite3` is an opaque type nor because the overhead of `std::shared_ptr`. You use, as the other answer specified, a `std::unique_tr`.

The only difference is how you setup the custom deleter. For `std::unique_ptr` it's part of the type definition, not a run-time parameter. So you need to do something like this:

```
struct sqlite3_deleter {
  void operator()(sqlite3* sql) {
    sqlite3_close_v2(sql);
  }
};

using unique_sqlite3 = std::unique_ptr<sqlite3, sqlite3_deleter>;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the example.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>

/* sqlite 3 interface */
struct sqlite3 {};
extern void sqlite3_close(sqlite3*);
extern int sqlite3_open(sqlite3**);

/* our boilerplate */
struct closer
{
    void operator()(sqlite3* p) const
    {
        sqlite3_close(p);
    }
};

using sqlite3_ptr = std::unique_ptr<sqlite3, closer>;

/* handy maker function */
sqlite3_ptr make_sqlite()
{
    sqlite3* buffer = nullptr;
    int err = sqlite3_open(&buffer);
    if (err) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to open sqlite");
    }
    return sqlite3_ptr(buffer);
}

int main()
{
    auto mysqlite = make_sqlite();
}
```

Comment: @user2079303 - Plus, `decltype(sqlite3_close)` here is `void(sqlite*)`, an incomplete type.

Comment: @user2079303 I prefer to build my own type so that actions taken in the destructor are explicitly controlled by me.

Comment: @StoryTeller `void(sqlite*)` isn't incomplete, even if `sqlite*` is, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @user2079303 - It's a function type. It's incomplete for the purposes of defining objects http://ideone.com/y22M0W . It will not resolve to `print`, is what I'm saying.

Comment: @Holt & StoryTeller Never mind about my previous comments, function pointer seems to work just fine. I was initially doubting because of your comments and my tests failed, but it was just that the deleter won't be called on a `nullptr`, so my test was faulty. `std::unique_ptr<sqlite3, decltype(&sqlite3_close)>` seems to work just fine: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae44df2b8c87ede4

Comment: @Holt function pointers do work. The deleter won't be default constructed unless you explicitly do so. There is one caveat though: The size of the unique_ptr will be doubled as the deleter pointer is also stored, so if you have more than one such pointer, or pass it around, it'll be marginally less efficient than a function object. I suppose that this argument was what I was hoping to hear from Richard :)

Comment: @user2079303 I wrongly assumed that `void (*)(sqlite3*)` was not an object type, and thus that such deleter would not meet the `FunctionObject` requirements, but actually it is, so I was wrong, my bad.

Comment: @user2079303 - Forgot about the c'tor accepting a deleter .

Answer (score 1):

## Solution with `shared_ptr`

I'm learning C++ and SQLite, so I had this question too. After reading this post, I tried some answers from it. The result is a working example and a small analysis.

- First create a custom deleter for the smart pointer.
- Then, create an empty share_ptr including the custom deleter
- Then, create an empty pointer for the DB handler (`sqlite3 * DB;`)
- Afterwards, open/create the DB.
- Link the raw pointer to the shared one.
- After the shared_ptr goes out of scope, it will delete the raw pointer too.

This is rather inefficient (*see conclusion*), but is the only way I manged to use smart pointers with sqlite3, so I decided to post this as an answer.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include<sqlite3.h>
#include<memory>

//Custom deleter
auto del_sqlite3 = [](sqlite3* pSqlite)
{
    std::cout << "Calling custom deleter." << std::endl;
    sqlite3_close_v2(pSqlite);
};

int main()
{
//Uncomment to run
//const char* dir = "C:\\test\\db_dir\\test.db"
openOrCreateDB(dir);
return 0;
}


int openOrCreateDB(const char* dirName)
{
    std::shared_ptr<sqlite3> DB(nullptr, del_sqlite3);//custom deleter
    auto pDB = DB.get();
    {
        int exit = sqlite3_open(dirName, &pDB);
        DB.reset(pDB);// Replace nullptr with pDB and link
     }
    return 0;
}
```

## Why smart pointers with sqlite3?

The main reason to use a smart pointer is to automate memory management and avoid memory leaks. So, this happens if we are thinking in allocating memory on the free store, using `new` and `delete`.

But I failed with all my attempts to allocate a database handler in the free store.

### Fail 1: using `sqlite3* DB = new sqlite3;`

```cpp
int openOrCreateDB(const char* dirName)
{
    sqlite3* DB = new sqlite3;//E0070: Incomplete type not allowed
    int exit = sqlite3_open(dirName, &DB);
    sqlite3_close(DB);
    return 0;
}
```

### Fail 2: using `share_ptr`

```cpp
static int openOrCreateDB(const char* dirName)
{
   
    std::shared_ptr<sqlite3> DB(new sqlite3, del_sqlite3);// Incomplete type not allowed
    auto pDB = DB.get();
    {
        int exit = sqlite3_open(dirName, &pDB);
        DB.reset(pDB);
     }
    
    return 0;
}
```

### Fail 3: using `make_shared`

I didn't even try. In *Meyers' Effective Modern C++*, Item 21 it is clear that you can't use `make_shared` to construct a smart pointer on the heap **with the custom deleter**.

## Conclusion

Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but it seems that SQLite does not like to allocate database handlers (sqlite3 objects) on the heap. So why use a smart pointer anyway? Even if you allocate the db handler on the stack, smart pointers uses more memory and more lines of code.

The other reason to use smart pointers is to manage ownership. But, in sqlite3, the workflow is quite repetitive: In a routine:

- Create a DB handler.
- Open DB, execute SQL statements, etc.
- Finalize statement
- Finalize DB connection.

So I can't see why should we pass arround a DB handler outside this workflow.

My recommendation is to keep using raw pointers and destroying them with `sqlite3_close(sqlite3 * ptr)`.